# Changing Text Highlighting Color in Matlab Editor

Tags: matlab, color-scheme

Is there any way to change the text highlighting color in the Matlab Editor from bright blue with white text to something easier on the eye, perhaps programatically (or in the matlab.prf file)?  I found the editor color and syntax highlighting preferences, however there isn't an option to set text highlighting.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I think this is inherited from operating system preferences, not set by MATLAB.

Comment: @nkjt You are completely right. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not set directly by MATLAB, but inherited from the operating system.

In Windows 7, running a "Basic" theme, it would be under:

Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization →　Personalization → Window Color (icon at bottom)

In the dropdown list, choose Item: Selected Items, and from there you can pick highlight color and font color.

Note: you shouldn't need to restart the computer, but you may need to restart MATLAB to see the change.